# IntelliJ IDEA bundled JRE - where are the log files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For example this is a part of my `idea64.vmoptions`

```
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
-Dsun.java2d.renderer.useLogger=true
-Dsun.java2d.renderer.gamma=1.5
-Dsun.java2d.renderer.verbose=true
-Dsun.java2d.debugfonts=true
-Djava2d.font.loadFontConf=true
```

So lot's of logging hopefully. Only - where are the logs? `~/.IdeaIC2017.1/system/log` has log files only for what IDEA itself is printing, nothing of the JVM seems to go there. Looked into `~/.java`, also nothing. This is with OpenJDK 8 on Linux.

Comment: Seeing the code: https://github.com/bourgesl/marlin-fx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/marlin/MarlinUtils.java , it looks like useLogger just means "use java.util.Logging". I don't see any specific setup for a log file, so I'm guessing the logs are ending up going to System.out. If you set useLogger to false the logs will definitely go to System.out.

Comment: Did you try to run IntelliJ IDEA from the terminal using `bin/idea.sh`? Does it show the logs?

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes, I did, and no there are no additional logs.